# Adding to a function through another javascript file

Tags: javascript, function, object, canvas

Hey I was wondering how I could add on to my function draw();  draw is used in my canvas engine to update everything within it.  What I want to do is create a standalone engine that could say be left un-edited and yet update completely new things just linked to it. For example-

```
function draw(){
    gameloop();
    cameraWrapper();
    context2D.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Now say I create a new app and use this engine.. I want to be able to just create a standalone file linked to the engine say a player object.

```
player = new object();
function playerupdate(){
     stuff;
     stuff;
}
```

Now how could I say add the playerupdate() function into the engine.js's draw() function without editing the engine.js file? would this be like a prototype? if so and even if its not and example would be greatly appreciated! 
If you have any questions please ask,
 thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think inheritance is a bit too complex for this... you can achieve all of what you want with just hooks.

Try something like this:

```
var postDrawHooks = [];
var draw = function(){
    // do stuff
    postDrawHooks.forEach(function(hook){hook()});
}

var playerUpdate = function(){...};
postDrawHooks.push(playerUpdate);
```

Comment: Hey I was playing with this but what about like cameraWrapper(player)? for some reason it wont let me push this if the function has something inside the parenthesis such as (player) ? any ideas?

Comment: You can update the hook signature to be `postDrawHooks.forEach(function(hook){hook(player)});` and accept that argument in your functions... `var playerUpdate = function(player){...};`

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly it is a prototype. If you do not wish to complicate yourself with prototypeing you can use a "home made" inheritance:

```
  Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    };

  Function.method('inherits', function(parent) {
        var d = {}, p = (this.prototype = new parent());
        this.method('uber', function uber(name) {
            if(!( name in d)) {
                d[name] = 0;
            }
            var f, r, t = d[name], v = parent.prototype;
            if(t) {
                while(t) {
                    v = v.constructor.prototype;
                    t -= 1;
                }
                f = v[name];
            } else {
                f = p[name];
                if(f == this[name]) {
                    f = v[name];
                }
            }
            d[name] += 1;
            r = f.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [1]));
            d[name] -= 1;
            return r;
        });
        return this;
    });
```

Now for a "class" (there is no such thing in js but this is the correct term ) you can make it inherit another "class" by using myCls.inherits(parentCls)

Comment: I don't really understand this yet... I'm pretty new to javascript and programming in general but I think I will need this soon and will keep this in mind! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason you couldn't trigger events for these framework actions?  that way anything listening for a 'draw' event could just hook their logic in that way?  if not actual eventing, something like the hooks suggested by @sudhir jonathan would work, though i would suggest creating a method to register generic hooks, this way you could call something like

```
game.register('draw',myFunctionReference);
```

and in game object

```
register : function (hook,func) {
    registeredHooks.push({'name' : hook, 'callback': func});
}
```

and in draw:

```
function draw(){
    gameloop();
    cameraWrapper();
    context2D.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (i=0; i < registeredHooks.length; i++) {
        var hook = registeredHooks[i];
        if (hook.name == 'draw') hook.callback();
    }
}
```