# Function hooking with drawing to canvas etc

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas

Hey guys In another question about function pushing-[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585261/adding-to-a-function-through-another-javascript-file/)
I was then given this code -

```
var postDrawHooks = [];
var draw = function(){
// do stuff
postDrawHooks.forEach(function(hook){hook()});
}

var playerUpdate = function(){...};
postDrawHooks.push(playerUpdate);
```

Which works very nicely, and allows you to push an outide function into another one like your game loop without having to edit your engine.js file for every game if you want to add an update to an object just push the hook.  Anyways I need a way to push drawing like Context2D.drawImage(blah blah blah); now when I try to push this like above below I get the  error trying to draw from null.

```
post_draw_render.push(context2D.drawImage(player.tilesheet, player.frameX,player.frameY, 46, 45, player.PosX, player.PosY+1, 46, 45));
```

I can't even use Context2D.drawImage anywhere oustide of my draw function and I don't know why any Ideas?
engine -

```
//engine vars//
function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context2D = canvas.getContext('2d');
setInterval(draw, 1000/FPS);
}
function draw() {
post_draw_function.forEach(function(hook){hook()});
gameloop();
context2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
post_draw_render.forEach(function(hook){hook});
//Basic Draw - context2D.drawImage(playerImg, player.PosX, player.PosY);
//Tilesheet draw - context2D.drawImage(tilesheet, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
context2D.fillStyle = "white";
context2D.font = 'bold 25px Times New Roman';
}
```

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but this sounds like a scope or precedence problem. Context2D is null for a reason; so it's either out of scope for the eventual hook, it's being called before the canvas has initialized, or it's being called before the resource you're using has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The object you are pushing into the array is not a function, it's the return value of a call to the drawImage function.

I think you want

```
post_draw_render.push(function () {
  context2D.drawImage(player.tilesheet, player.frameX,player.frameY, 46, 45, player.PosX, player.PosY+1, 46, 45);
});
```